# how to move one component to another in angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

could you please tell me how to move one component to another in angular ?.I want to show second page when user click on button ..it should desplay this 
component

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/NXo357FdZ5ir834JYuXi?p=preview

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'second',
})

@View({
  templateUrl: 'second/second.html'
})
export class secondComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **Router** Component, Click [Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for more info.
I think It's better to have a main component which is responsible to hold configurations about router component and app's routes.like this:

```
    import {Component} from "angular2/core";
    import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,RouteConfig} from "angular2/router";
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })

    @RouteConfig([
        //define your routes here...
    ])

    export class MainComponent {

    }
```

Once you've defined your routes,Initialize it in your *AppComponent*'s constructor:

```
constructor(private _router:Router) {
}
```

and then You should change your `onclck` function to this:

```
onclck(){
    this._router.navigate(['SecondComponent']);
}
```

`SecondComponent` is your second component's route name which is defined in your `@RouteConfing`.

**EDIT:** Here it is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LjUo1Bn8Mc3cO8cxFd4C?p=preview). Look carefully at *app\boot.ts* file.

Comment: could you please share plunker

Comment: @user944513 Here it is

Comment: what is this provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}

Comment: There are two location strategies in angular 2,By default `PathLocationStrategy` is enabled,Click [here](http://yakovfain.com/2015/11/02/angular-2-router-high-level-overview/) for more info.